# In Chrome not getting an onClick() on a FocusPanel when focus was on a TextArea that has registered onChange and onBlur handlers

Tags: gwt

I don't like using Button-s in my app because they are visually too heavyweight.  I suppose I could use a Button having an image, but I found what I thought was a simpler solution that did not require using an image: just make an InlineLabel and put it inside a FocusPanel and then intercept the onClick() events on the FocusPanel.  This also puts the InlineLabel into the tab order which is also something I want.  (However maybe this idiom is somehow the source of the problem.)

I have a TextArea and after it in the tab order a FocusPanel/InlineLabel.  I want that whenever focus leaves the TextArea that I get an event so I can hide the TextArea and show a Label right next to it and copy the TextArea text into that label.  That is, when you leave the text area by any means, your content turns into a label.  (Yes, I handled the Cross-Site Scripting Attack; thanks.)  This works fine if the user, say, hits tab: all the above happens, plus focus goes to the next thing, namely the FocusPanel/InlineLabel.

What does not work is if the user is editing and then just clicks on the FocusPanel/InlineLabel.  Before I added the onBlur() and onChange() handlers to the TextBox, clicking on the FocusPanel/InlineLabel reliably (1) put the focus onto the FP/IL and (2) fired a ClickEvent on the FP/IL.  Now that the TextArea has the new handlers, when the user clicks on the FP/IL, I get the onChange() (and sometimes onBlur() and sometimes not on the TextArea, another issue) but then the FocusPanel/InlineLabel no longer gets a click event.

Any ideas?  I'm wondering if this is a bug in Chrome or in my understanding of GWT.  Glancing at other questions, it seems as if event handling in GWT simpler than just onClick() seems to cause all kinds of weirdness.

I'm using Chrome 16.0.912.77 which it says is up to date; I'm running on OS X 10.6.8.