# GWT handling onBlur is also stopping the propagation of the event

Tags: gwt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [in Chrome not getting an onClick() on a FocusPanel when focus was on a TextArea that has registered onChange and onBlur handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170566/in-chrome-not-getting-an-onclick-on-a-focuspanel-when-focus-was-on-a-textarea)

In my GWT app I register a BlurHandler on a TextArea so that I can save the changes and go from edit mode back to view mode if the focus moves elsewhere.  This works, but also seems to defeat the effect of the event that moved the focus, at least on Chrome in devmode.  For example, if the user clicks on an Anchor, the TextBox gets the onBlur() and then the Anchor does not get the onClick(); whereas before I registered the onBlur, the Anchor would get the onClick().  This seems to be quite reliable (again, in Chrome in devmode).  I am being careful to not call event.stopPropagation() or event.preventDefault().  Any ideas how I can get the onBlur and also the onClick() ?

Comment: Yea, I posted that also :-).  It got no answers and my statement above is much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. I was not able to track the source problem though. I did enable dev toolbar / firebug and set event breakpoints to test; it does look like the click event was not triggered after the blur action. After playing around for many hours (and I'm not quite sure what inspired me to try this), I dropped the onblur action in a timer with executed delay at about 300ms. That seemed to work for me. I think it might have something to do with the fact that my action slightly modified the page and visibility of items, witch re-rendered the page and I can only guess that the single-threaded browser model killed the click event which was not longer on the right area.

```
      textBox.addBlurHandler(new BlurHandler()
      {
        @Override
        public void onBlur(BlurEvent event)
        {
            Timer delayTimer = new Timer()
            {
              @Override
              public void run()
              {
                 //do stuff
              }
            };
            delayTimer.schedule(300);
         }
    });


           anchor.addClickHandler(....)
```

Comment: Thanks! I had troubles with click event. In FocusPanel I had 2 listeners onFocus & onClick, somehow only onFocus event was triggered. Your solution with timer works in my case too.